# Selecting 'Yes' on Excel prompt with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I'm running into a problem where each time I open up (manually) a specific downloaded excel file, I get this prompt `We found a problem with some content in file.xls. Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes.`

When I click 'Yes' it repairs and opens the file, and everything seems to be there. I'm having issues because I have built a macro that performs some data clean up on this file, and due to the message, the macro is no longer able to open the file up. Right now I have

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

at the beginning of my code, which results in any error message not being displayed. As a result my macro then throws an error saying it was unable to open the file, which is true because due to the type of message it is, it requires me to click 'Yes' in order to open it.

Is there a way to program the prompt to always select yes? Better yet, is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Have you tried resolving the issue that is causing that "we found a problem" error?

Comment: @Chrismas007 I believe [it's pretty difficult to specifically locate this type of error](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f8abedda-619e-4f9d-97a5-fba2fcacd8c2/excel-found-unreadable-content-in-filenamexls-do-you-want-to-recover-the-contents-of-this?forum=excel) due to Excel being non-specific about corruption causes. That being said, the closest thing I've been able to find for automatically selecting an option is [`Application.SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx) to process an _Enter_ key press.

Comment: @Chrismas007 This is a file that is being downloaded from another site, which means until the moment I open the file, I have no interaction with it. If I have to manually open it to find and fix the issue each time I download it, then it defeats the purpose of having it automatically open the file for me before cleaning it up.

Comment: Thanks @Dan I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: @Dan Unfortunately once I take away the `DisplayAlerts = False` statement other error messages that were being suppressed before are now throwing errors with the VBA before the `SendKeys` statement even has a chance to run.

Comment: Excel has an [option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195811(v=office.11).aspx) to attempt to repair a workbook upon opening. The documentation I linked to is for 2003, but it is still an option in Office 2016.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 since I can't see the entire situation this is just a guess, but what if you set `DisplayAlerts=False` afte the `SendKeys` statement and implement the `Wait` part of the expression to make sure that Enter is pressed? I'm not sure what other error messages you are suppressing and if they occur before or after you are opening the desired file.

Comment: Do you have any idea why you get the message in the first place? Isn't it strange that the file is always 'corrupt' but never misses data? It suggests that the format is not what excel expects. The file may be of another type and should be opened in an alternative way. Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040386/is-it-possible-to-automatically-repair-corrupt-excel-workbooks